# How to ask forgiveness for hurting people?

Tags: allah

I cussed at customer call. I called my mom and before the ringing there was a description about corona virus. I got irritated hearing it over and over again i cussed at it. I didn’t know that call centre agents hear whatever we say until today. I am deeply sorry for my actions. I did it many times in the past. I am deeply remorseful because so many people were hurt because of my actions. How can i ask forgiveness for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you feel regret and feel remorse this is a sign of IMAM. And if you have imam you still have hope in Allah if you know where these people live or work etc. Ask for their forgiveness if you don’t make dua for them and if they don’t give you now it’s up to Allah and if you do good deeds still feel remorse Allah will ease your worries Insha’Allah

Comment: I don’t know these people and i don’t know where they live. But still i feel bad. I am deeply sorry for the pain i caused them. But i am worried about what if they caused harm to themselves?  Am i responsible?   Because It's not the first time, i did it in the past too. But i was unaware of the fact that they could hear me.

Comment: Don’t let shaitan think that Allah will not forgive no matter what sin it is EVEN IF YOU KILL SOMEONE! Just make dua don’t worry I don’t know if you will be responsible. But just make dua for them and if you feel remorse and regret Allah will erase that sin like it never happened Insha’Allah never lose hope he is the most merciful most forgiving.